# How To Send ID into 2 Process on 1 Controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core-mvc

I learned a basic asp.net core code and now i want to make process like this:
I Have a datatable to display Header Record, inside that i have a button in single row, when i click the button i want to redirect into other page within data in the table and display Line(Detail) data, so i'm using code like this 
script on form 1

```
function Edit(ID) {
        window.location.href = "/MyController/ShowEdit?ID=" + ID;
    }
```

and then in the new page i want to display the data using datatable, but my script on datatable not execute by the process
script form 2

```
 $("#table1").DataTable({
            //Design Layout
            stateSave: true,
            autoWidth: true,
            scrollX: true,
            scrollY: false,

            //ServerSide
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,

            //Paging Setup
            paging: true,


            //searching Setup
            searching: { regex: true },

            //ajax Filter
            ajax: {
                url: "/MyController/MyNewTable?ID="@ViewBag.ID,
                //"dataSrc": '',
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json",
                dataType: "json",
                data: function (d) {
                    return JSON.stringify(d);
                }
            },
.......................skipp...................................
```

maybe i need another method to display the detail data, i'm not using modal in form 1 because i wan't to make modal edit in form 2.

That's My form 2

```
 <div class="card-header">
     <h3 class="card-title">Edit @ViewBag.ID</h3>
 </div>
```

i want to get the viewbag.id to make a parameter in the data table

and then that'my Controller

```
public async Task<IActionResult> ShowEdit(int ID)
   {
   var myData = await _MyContext.MyTable.FirstOrDefaultAsync(a => a.Id == ID);
            if(myData == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            ViewBag.ID = myData.Id;
            return View(myData);
  }
```

and the ViewBag Working fine

and then i make class to display the detail

```
 public IActionResult MyNewTable([FromBody]DTParameters dtParameters, int ID)
        {
            var searchBy = dtParameters.Search?.Value;
            var orderCriteria = string.Empty;
            var orderDescendingDirection = true;
}
...............Skipp..................
```

please help me to solve this code
maybe i can get the id without using viewbag and in the button form 1 can send the id into 2 class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is the correct way . `ID` is not persist across requests from a client. So you need to pass `id` from page to `MyNewTable` server side function as query string using AJAX .

You can persist `ID` with session/tempdata ... , then you can directly read the id on server side . Please read [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-2.2) for more details .